# How get a more transparent message from error 1216-Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I'm using c# MVC with entity framework 6 to developer a MVC application.

The database server is MySQL all tables are INNODB and when I updated a record I get the follow error

> "ERROR 1216: 1216: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails."

I know that this is error is caused by foreign key violation, and in this case I know which key has the problem, but I wanna a transparent way to show for user or developer which key have a problem. I want for MySQL to show a full error like MsSQL shows:

> "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__XXX_Table_XXX". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX", table "TableXXXX", column 'Id_XXXX'.

There is a some way to do that in MySQL or entity framework 6?

Comment: Showing that error to the user isn't a good idea. The developer should see the error when it breaks at dB.submitchanges()

Comment: I wanna show error for user and the support team give a more fast response for final user, and fix problem more fast